# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) [related to mysql]

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, mysql

So I was facing some problems when installing a LAMP server a week ago. I couldn't solve them back then and since I didn't have lot of time I quit trying. Now, I tried to install some new software and my mistakes are back to haunt me I can say. Every time I run sudo apt-get I get errors with some mysql relevant lines in the description.
For example,here's the output when I run sudo apt-get autoremove:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mysql-common (5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mysql-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-client-5.7:
 mysql-client-5.7 depends on mysql-common (>= 5.5); however:
  Package mysql-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-client-5.7 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server-5.7:
 mysql-server-5.7 depends on mysql-client-5.7 (>= 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package mysql-client-5.7 is not configured yet.
 mysql-server-5.7 depends on mysql-common (>= 5.6.22-1~); however:
  Package mysql-common is not configured yet.
 mysql-server-5.7 depends on mysql-common (>= 5.5); however:
  Package mysql-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-common
 mysql-client-5.7
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have searched about this error and most answers were suggesting to use autoremove or install -f(same output).
Any help?

Comment: Please edit your question to explain clearly what the "problems" were when you tried (and failed) into install the elements of your LAMP server. If you were following online instructions, a link would be very helpful.

Comment: To be precise, I initially managed to install mysql properly, but had some problems with root access. So, I tried uninstalling and reconfiguring and after that to remove completely.